# Ansible role task delegation

Tags: ansible

Given the below inventory/role/playbook examples, how can I delegate a task within a role to localhost and have it print the ip address of the node the role is executing on?

To be clear, my desired output is the IP address of `app1` in this scenario. However, I want localhost to print that IP Address. I don't want the print task to run on the `app1` node.

```
## inventory
[app_nodes]
app1
app2

## Role: foobar/main.yml
task:
    debug:
        msg: {{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}
    delegate_to: localhost

## playbook
hosts: app_nodes
roles:
    - { role: foobar }
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what you ask about. `debug` always prints the information on the control node and it always uses facts from the target host. What do you imply by trying to devise a workaround -- that without it a message appears on a console of the target machine?

Comment: yes - I want to print on the control node. Debug is only chosen as an example. I needed to delegate the task to localhost, but use the variables from each target node in the playbook.

Comment: There is no need to delegate `debug` task to localhost, because it **never** runs remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the `host_vars` magic variable combined with the `inventory_hostname`

```
## inventory
[app_nodes]
app1
app2

## Role: foobar/main.yml
task:
    debug:
        msg: {{host_vars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_facts']['default_ipv4_address']}}
    delegate_to: localhost

## playbook
hosts: app_nodes
roles:
    - { role: foobar }
```

On run, this outputs the IP address of app1 and app2.

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsense. It is the same as if you'd write `debug: var=default_ipv4_address` without any delegation nor using `hostvars`.